# Get one array from output

Tags: php, curl, location, ip

Help with getting a specific array.
What this script does is go to http://www.iplocation.net/index.php?query=223.196.190.40&submit=Query and get the information of country, city, ips etc. and outputs it like ;

```
      [IP Address] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      [Country] => Country
      [Region] => Region
      [City] => City
      [ISP] => Provider
```

Now i just want it to get one array, the array for [City]

Here is the code what i have right now ;

```
    <?php
  require_once( "simple_html_dom.php" );

  $ip_info  = ip_info( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 1 );
  print_r( $ip_info );
  /**
   * It will output...
    Array
    (
      [IP Address] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      [Country] => Country
      [Region] => Region
      [City] => City
      [ISP] => Provider
    )
  **/


  /**
   * ip_info()
   * @param $ip - IP address you want to fetch data from
   * @param $provider IP provider ( 1 = IP2Location, 2 = IPligence, 3 = IP Address Labs, 4 = MaxMind )
   * @return array
   */
  function ip_info( $ip = "127.0.0.1", $provider = 1 ) {
    $indx = array(
      1 =>  10,
      2 =>  11,
      3 =>  12,
      4 =>  13
    );
    $data = array();
    $url  = "http://www.iplocation.net/index.php";
    $ch   = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "query=".urlencode( $ip )."&submit=Query" );
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );

    $html = str_get_html( $response );
    if ( $table = $html->find( "table", $indx[$provider] ) ) {
      if ( $tr1 = $table->find( "tr", 1 ) ) {
        if ( $headers = $tr1->find( "td" ) ) {
          foreach( $headers as $header ) {
            $data[trim( $header->innertext )] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      if ( $tr2 = $table->find( "tr", 3 ) ) {
        reset( $data );
        if ( $values = $tr2->find( "td" ) ) {
          foreach( $values as $value ) {
            $data[key( $data )] = trim( $value->plaintext );
            next( $data );
          }
        }
      }
    }
    unset( $html, $table, $tr1, $tr2, $headers, $values );
    return $data;
  }
?>
```

This will output

```
  [IP Address] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      [Country] => Country
      [Region] => Region
      [City] => City
      [ISP] => Provider
```

It must be only city, so if the city is new-york for the IP than output New-york instead of

```
  [IP Address] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  [Country] => Country
  [Region] => Region
  [City] => City
  [ISP] => Provider
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$ip_info = ip_info($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 1);
$city = $ip_info->City;
```

Or modify the function's `return` to only return City, which would make `$ip_info` equal the city:

```
return $data->City;
```

And if you truly don't care about the other information you can just look for City specifically it in your `foreach` loops with a simple `if` statement:

```
...
foreach( $headers as $header ) {
    if (trim( $header->innertext ) == 'City') {
        $data[trim( $header->innertext )] = null;
    }
}
...
foreach( $values as $value ) {
    if (key( $data )) == 'City') {
        $data[key( $data )] = trim( $value->plaintext );
        next( $data );
    }
}
...
return $data->City;
```